# jsonb_set: how to set a number, not string, value in a jsonb field?

Tags: json, postgresql

In Postgres, how to set a number, not string, value in a jsonb field?

`jsonb_set` wants a jsonb value as the 3rd argument, but numbers can't be casted to json.
Example code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_age(person jsonb)
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  -- language declaration required
$func$
DECLARE
  age NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'input %', person::TEXT;
    age := (person->'age')::NUMERIC + 1;
    RAISE NOTICE 'new age %', age;


    -- person := jsonb_set(person, '{age}', age); 
    -- this fails: function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, numeric) does not exist
    -- how to set a number, not string, value in the 'age' jsonb field?

    RETURN person;
END
$func$;

SELECT update_age('{"name": "John", "age": 30}');
-- desired result: {"name": "John", "age": 31}
-- not {"name": "John", "age": "31"}
```

Comment: Storing the "age" is usually a bad idea. You will have to update it regularly. A much better idea is to store the date of birth and then calculate the age on the fly when you retrieve the data

Comment: Right, thanks :) Not storing the age, it was a simplified example from more complex code. Appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The third parameter to `jsonb_set()` needs to be a jsonb value. To convert a number to a proper jsonb value, use `to_jsonb()`, not a cast.

```
person := jsonb_set(person, '{age}', to_jsonb(age));
```

---

A `language sql` function would be more efficient though:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_age(person jsonb)
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE sql 
AS
$func$
  select jsonb_set(person, '{age}', to_jsonb((person ->> 'age'):: numeric + 1));
$func$
immutable;
```

Comment: Can also do the ::jsonb after the variable, same thing
 jsonb_set(person, '{age}', age::jsonb, (true/false) );

Comment: Have tried `::jsonb`, but it gave cannot typecast to jsonb error